# Get Bibliography using biblatex

Tags: latex, tex, bibliography, biblatex

I am using the below code for citations.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array,booktabs,dcolumn,threeparttable,adjustbox,dirtytalk,multirow,tabularx,booktabs,longtable,placeins,tikz}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib,style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\psset{unit=2cm}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=red}

\addbibresource{segmentation.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a sample \cite{sample}.

\end{document}
```

The output that I am getting is:

[image]

However, I need it like (Author, Year).
Also, I want the bibliography to appear in the paper, and not able to do so and I want the entire Author, Year to get linked, that is, when I click on it, it takes me to the relevant page in the bibliography.

Could you please help me with that?

Thank You

Comment: You are again asking multiple questions in one post. This website works best if you only ask about one problem in each post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- to get a bibliography in your document, you need the `\printbibliography` macro
- to get parenthesis around your citation, use `\citep{...}`

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array,booktabs,dcolumn,threeparttable,adjustbox,dirtytalk,multirow,tabularx,booktabs,longtable,placeins,tikz}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib,style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\psset{unit=2cm}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=red}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a sample \citep{knuth:ct}.


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You! Brackets and bibliography work. But I am still not able to link entire Author, Year. Only year is referenced

Comment: This means that entire Author, Year turns blue. In the image, only Year is blue.

Comment: @AnishaGarg The extend of the link is completely unrelated to adding a bibliography or adding parenthesis. Only ask one question per post.